# Performing async method in a loop in node.js and waiting for result

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the code below, how do I make **console.log(output)** execute only when all the asynchronous callbacks are finished?

```
var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    asyncMethodWithCallback(param, function(error, result){
        output.push(result);
    });
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the length of output against x if they are the same log the output

```
var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    asyncMethodWithCallback(param, function(error, result){
        output.push(result);
        if(output.length == x){
            asyncComplete();
        }
    });
}

function asyncComplete(){
   console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: You could also use a promises library here, but it feels a little overkill for a simple scenario like this (and one where the method uses a callback rather than returns a promise)